# MFC - Overriding the virtual method OnUpdateValue() from the CMFCPropertyGridProperty class

Tags: c++, inheritance, mfc, virtual-functions

in a MFC Project of mine, I was trying to override the virtual method `BOOL OnUpdateMethod()` from the `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` Class. The method's new implementation should update some child properties whenever a combobox on a parent property is changed.

So, I've created a new class using the `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` as a base class. Here's my problem: I am not being able to move forward because the compiler states to me that there is no appropriate constructor available (*Error C2512*). So, I've tried to declare and implement the same constructor of `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` and more errors are generated!

What should I do in order to implement any public virtual method properly? I believe that the solution for this is really simple, but I am kind of a noob at C++ and MFC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb983599.aspx), the constructor requires between 1 and 3 parameters. You need to supply those parameters via the initialization list of your own constructor.

```
class CMyGridProperty: public CMFCPropertyGridProperty
{
public:
    CMyGridProperty(const CString& strGroupName,
                    DWORD_PTR dwData=0,
                    BOOL bIsValueList=FALSE)
       : CMFCPropertyGridProperty(strGroupName, dwData, bIsValueList)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok, apparently it is working fine! Now I've tried to test it, but I didn't had much success either. Is there any documentation or tutorial in order to implement this kind of event?
Thanks!

Comment: @Mudkip I'm afraid I'm not familiar with this particular class. You might ask another question with more details about the exact problem you're having.